# enum variable is showing error even after declaring in C

Tags: c, enums

I tried to learn enumeration in c and my doubt is the enum variable is showing error even after i have declared it but the same code works fine when i use it via a function?

The code which is showing error:

the variable per1 and per2 are showing error, what is the reason for it?

```
enum mar_status
    {
        single = 100, married = 200, divorced = 300, widowed = 400
    };
enum mar_status per1, per2;
per1 = single;
per2 = married
```

The code which is working fine:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void global();
int main(){
    global();
    return 0;
}

void global(){
    enum mar_status
        {
            single = 100, married = 200, divorced = 300, widowed = 400
        };
    enum mar_status per1, per2;
    per1 = single;
    per2 = married;
    printf("The person 1 is %d and person 2 is %d\n",per1,per2);
}
```

Thanks for the people who helps to solve my query!

Comment: How about civil partnership?

Comment: Your first snippet is not a [mcve]. But if I assume correctly and it's all in file scope, just search for the error of [so]. It's been asked numerous times already.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: how about complicated?

Comment: `per2 = married` in first snippet is missing `;`

Comment: @EdHeal what is **civil partnership**?

Comment: @Gerhard my mistake but even still it is not the solution to the problem. the error is variable per1 and per2 are marked as error!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civil_partnership_in_the_United_Kingdom and https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/family/couple/registered-partners/index_en.htm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civil_union

Comment: @Jayakumar What is the error?

Comment: @StoryTeller ok will read about it and thanks for your view

Comment: @Gerhard error : this declaration has no storage class or type specifier

Comment: Post the broken code, not the working code

Comment: @M.M thats all the broken code Im trying to assign value to enum variable globally. While assigning I get error.

Answer (score 1):

C does not allow executable statements outside functions.
The first five lines are declarations and are correct.
The last two lines are executable statements:

```
per1 = single;
per2 = married;
```

and must be placed inside a function, e.g. `main` as in your second piece of code.

You can also do the declaration with an initial value if you want to keep it outside a function:

```
enum mar_status {
  single = 100, married = 200, divorced = 300, widowed = 400 };

enum mar_status per1 = single;
enum mar_status per2 = married;

int main(){
  printf("The person 1 is %d and person 2 is %d\n",per1,per2);
  return 0;
}
```